# Redundancy regarding product types and tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

In Haskell you have product types and you have tuples.

You use tuples if you don't want to associate a dedicated type with the value, and you can use product types if you wish to do so.

However I feel there is redundancy in the notation of product types

```
data Foo = Foo (String, Int, Char)
data Bar = Bar String Int Char
```

Why are there both kinds of notations? Is there any case where you would prefer one the other?

I guess you can't use record notation when using tuples, but that's just a convenience problem. Another thing might be the notion of order in tuples, as opposed to product types, but I think that's just due to the naming of the functions `fst` and `snd`.

Answer (score 7):

[@chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43047080/1523776) is about the technical differences in terms of Haskell's evaluation model. I hope to give you some insight into the philosophy of this sort of typed programming.

In category theory we generally work with objects "up to isomorphism". Your `Bar` is of course isomorphic to `(String, Int, Char)`, so from a categorical perspective they're the same thing.

```
bar_tuple :: Iso' Bar (String, Int, Char)
bar_tuple = iso to from
    where to (Bar s i c) = (s, i, c)
          from (s, i, c) = Bar s i c
```

In some sense tuples are a Platonic form of product type, in that they have no meaning beyond being a collection of disparate values. All the other product types can be mapped to and from a plain old tuple.

So why not use tuples everywhere, when all Haskell types ultimately boil down to a sum of products? It's about communication. As Martin Fowler says,

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.

Names are important! Writing down a custom product type like

```
data Customer = Customer { name :: String, address :: String }
```

imbues the type `Customer` with *meaning* to the person reading the code, unlike `(String, String)` which just means "two strings".

Custom types are particularly useful when you want to enforce invariants by hiding the representation of your data and using *smart constructors*:

```
newtype NonEmpty a = NonEmpty [a]

nonEmpty :: [a] -> Maybe (NonEmpty a)
nonEmpty [] = Nothing
nonEmpty xs = Just (NonEmpty xs)
```

Now, if you don't export the `NonEmpty` constructor, you can force people to go through the `nonEmpty` smart constructor. If someone hands you a `NonEmpty` value you may safely assume that it has at least one element.

You can of course represent `Customer` as a tuple under the hood and expose evocatively-named field accessors,

```
newtype Customer = Bar (String, String)
name, address :: Customer -> String
name (Customer (n, a)) = n
address (Customer (n, a)) = a
```

but this doesn't really buy you much, except that it's now cheaper to convert `Customer` to a tuple (if, say, you're writing performance-sensitive code that works with a tuple-oriented API).

If your code is intended to solve a particular problem - which of course is the whole point of writing code - it pays to not just solve the problem, but make it look like you've solved it too. Someone - maybe you in a couple of years - is going to have to read this code and understand it with no *a priori* knowledge of how it works. Custom types are a very important communication tool in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

The type

```
data Foo = Foo (String, Int, Char)
```

represents a double-lifted tuple. It values comprise

```
undefined
Foo undefined
Foo (undefined, undefined, undefined)
etc.
```

This is usually troublesome. Because of this, it's rare to see such definitions in actual code. We either have plain data types

```
data Foo = Foo String Int Char
```

or `newtype`s

```
newtype Foo = Foo (String, Int, Char)
```

The `newtype` can be just as inconvenient to use, but at least it 
does not double-lift the tuple: `undefined` and `Foo undefined` are now equal values.

The `newtype` also provides zero-cost conversion between a plain tuple and `Foo`, in both directions.

You can see such `newtype`s in use e.g. when the programmer needs a different instance for some type class, than the one already associated with the tuple. Or, perhaps, it is used in a "smart constructor" idiom.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect the pattern used in `Foo` to be frequent. There is slight difference in what the constructor acts like: `Foo :: (String, Int, Char) -> Foo` as opposed to `Bar :: String -> Int -> Char -> Bar`. Then `Foo undefined` and `Foo (undefined, ..., ...)` are strictly speaking different things, whereas you miss one level of undefinedness in `Bar`.